# Extract already know shape from image

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv

I´m trying to extract this piece

[image]

From this

[image]

Ive tried to detect shapes, no way, train an haarscascade...(Idont have negatives) no way, .... the position can vary (not all of them are inserted) and the angle is not the same.. I cannot crop one by one :-(

Any suggestion ??? Thanks in advance

PS Original image is here https://pasteboard.co/JaTSoJF.png (sorry > 2Mb)

After working on @ganeshtata we got

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('cropsmall.png')
height, width = img.shape[:2]
green_channel = img[:,0:] # Blue channel extraction
res = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(green_channel, None, 3, 7, 21) # Non-local means denoising
cv2.imshow('denoised',res)
edges = cv2.Canny(res, 11, 11, 3) # Edge detection
kernel = np.ones((30, 30),np.uint8)
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(edges, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel) # Morphological closing
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(closing, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) # Find all contours in the image

for cnt in contours: # Iterate through all contours
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt) # Reject contours whose height is less than half the image height
    if h < height / 2:
        continue
    y = 0 # Assuming that all shapes start from the top of the image
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), \
          (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.imshow('IMG',img)
    cv2.imwrite("test.jpg",img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

That gives us

[image]

Not bad...

Comment: Are you trying to extract all the patterns matching the pattern shown, or are you trying to find patches which exactly match your piece?

Comment: I'm trying to extract the content in the tube... can be as yellow as the 5th one or clear as the 4th, thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the following approach to extract the pattern specified in the question.

1. Read the image and extract the blue channel from the image.

   ```
   import cv2
   import numpy as np
   img = cv2.imread('image.png') 
   height, width = img.shape[:2]
   blue_channel = img[:,:,0]
   ```

   Blue Channel - 
   [image]
2. Apply OpenCV's [Non-local Means Denoising algorithm](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/d69/tutorial_py_non_local_means.html) on the blue channel image. This ensures that most of the random noise in the image is smoothed.

   ```
   res = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(blue_channel, None, 3, 7, 21)
   ```

   Denoised image - 
   [image]
3. Apply Canny edge detection.

   ```
   edges = cv2.Canny(res, 1, 10, 3)
   ```

   Edge output - 
   [image]
4. Apply [Morpological Closing](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html) to try and close small gaps/holes in the image.

   ```
   kernel = np.ones((30, 30),np.uint8)
   closing = cv2.morphologyEx(edges, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
   ```

   Image after applying morphological closing - 
   [image]
5. Find all contours in the image using [cv2.findContours](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html). After finding all contours, we can determine the bounding box of each contour using [cv2.boundingRect](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html).

   ```
   im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(closing, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) # Find all contours

   for cnt in contours: # Iterate through all contours
       x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt) $ Get contour bounding box
       if h < height / 2: # Reject contours whose height is less than half the image height
           continue
       y = 0  # Assuming that all shapes start from the top of the image
       cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), \
             (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
   ```
6. Final result - 
   [image]

The complete code -

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('image.png')
height, width = img.shape[:2]
blue_channel = img[:,:,0] # Blue channel extraction
res = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(blue_channel, None, 3, 7, 21) # Non-local means denoising
edges = cv2.Canny(res, 1, 10, 3) # Edge detection
kernel = np.ones((30, 30),np.uint8)
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(edges, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel) # Morphological closing
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(closing, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) # Find all contours in the image

for cnt in contours: # Iterate through all contours
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt) # Reject contours whose height is less than half the image height
    if h < height / 2:
        continue
    y = 0 # Assuming that all shapes start from the top of the image
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), \
          (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
```

Note - This approach works for the sample image posted by you. It might/might not generalize for all images.

Comment: OMG !!! Thanks a lot Canny drives me crazy before your suggestion.

Comment: as you said it does not work with similar images... https://pasteboard.co/JaTkOEm.jpg but your approach is really good

Comment: Can you post the original image as part of the question?

Comment: it is really a pain to get it working, at the end cropping at origin (pure crop)  https://pasteboard.co/JaTQ3TY.png got https://pasteboard.co/JaTPycz.png the real original image is as ugly as this one  https://pasteboard.co/JaTSoJF.png we only need the end of the tube.... but we can play cropping when having each individual

Comment: Those are nice results! Do you want help with anything else? Or does this answer your question? You could also upvote the answer if it helped you. Thanks!